# Angular How to check radio button by default without NgModel

Tags: angular, radio-button

I checked all question here before. How can I select one radio button by default without ngModel?

```
<input type="radio" formControlName="calculate" value="1">
<input type="radio" formControlName="calculate" value="2">
<input type="radio" formControlName="calculate" value="3">
```

If anybody has same problem. Here right solution. Thanks to Andrei:

```
<input type="radio" formControlName="calculate" [value]="1">
<input type="radio" formControlName="calculate" [value]="2">
<input type="radio" formControlName="calculate" [value]="3">
```

And Init:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form.controls['calculate'].setValue(1);
  }
```

Comment: set the correct inital value of your formControl. E.g "1","2" or "3"

Comment: Thanks I tried this at init: this.form.controls['calculate'].setValue(1); but doesn`t work, too.

Comment: try `.setValue('1')` or make values as `number` on your html like this `input [value]="1"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting the initial value to 1,2 or 3.

```
initForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      calculate: ['1']
    })
  }
```

Second way is to patch value-

```
initSelection() {
    this.form.patchValue({
      calculate: '2'
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simlple use `[checked]='true'` it will check your radio button by default.

```
<input type="radio" [checked]='true' formControlName="calculate" value="1">
<input type="radio" [checked]='true' formControlName="calculate" value="2">
<input type="radio" [checked]='true' formControlName="calculate" value="3">
```

Comment: This solution is not working. I tried this bevore and now again to check if I did mistake

Comment: I tried this in my code its working here. Try only checked like this

<input type="radio" checked  formControlName="calculate" value="3">